# Use polar co-ordinates to show the fixed point of the dynamical system $x^\prime = x-y-x^{3}$ and $y^\prime = x+y-y^{3}$ has distance <2 from (0,0)

Tags: polar-coordinates, chaos-theory, nonlinear-dynamics

Using polar co-ordinates to solve the dynamical system:
$$x^\prime = x-y-x^{3}$$

$$y^\prime = x+y-y^{3}$$

I have arrived at: \begin{align}
  r' &= r-r^3(cos^4\theta+sin^4\theta)\\
  \theta' &= 1+\frac{r^2}{4}sin4\theta
\end{align}

However I am now stuck on how to proceed in finding the fixed point. I know that I need to make both $r'$ and $\theta'$ equal to zero but can't find the breakthrough as to what values $r$ and $\theta$ would need to take to achieve this. Any help with this is appreciated.

Comment: $1+r^2/4 *sin^4 \theta$ is always positive.

Comment: Okay, so how would this get me started on determining the fixed point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will not be a fixed point, but a limiting cycle. This takes the form of a closed curve whose distance from the origin must be proved less than $2$ at all points.

You just keep going from your expression for $r'$.  Dividing out a factor of $r$ gives for $r\ge 2$:

$r'/r\le1-4(\cos^4\theta+\sin^4\theta)$

And then

$\cos^4\theta+\sin^4\theta=(1/2)[(\cos^4\theta+2\cos^2\theta\sin^2\theta+\sin^4\theta)+(\cos^4\theta-2\cos^2\theta\sin^2\theta+\sin^4\theta)]$

$=(1/2)[(\color{blue}{\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta})^2+(\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta)^2]$

Given the value of the blue expression we conclude that $r'/r\le-1$ for $r\ge2$ with obvious implications for the motion of the object in that range.

A little homework for you: using the identity given for $\cos^4\theta+\sin^4\theta$, prove that the limit cycle actually lies in $1\le r\le\sqrt2$.

Comment: Great, thanks. I have followed through using your identity to show that $r^\prime >0$ implies $r^2<1$ and therefore $r<1$. 

Similarly, $r^\prime <0$ implies $r^2>2$ and therefore $r>\sqrt2$.

This results in the annular trapping region $1\le r\le\sqrt2$ as you have mentioned. This helps to answer my second question on this topic as I am required to show that the system has a periodic solution which I believe this working is sufficient for.

Comment: But just to return to my original question, is there definitely not a specific "fixed point" that I am looking for? Perhaps the wording of the question is misleading but it states exactly "Show that the system has a single fixed point at a distance smaller than 2 from the origin". I understand clearly how our use of polar co-ordinates and manipulation of trig identities clearly shows that any solution has $r<2$ but the wording of the question "single fixed point" makes me believe there may be a specific point that needs to be identified.

Comment: Well, the origin is trivially a fixed point, but I was thinking they wanted you to identify the less trivial solution of the cycle and misspoke.  In any event, your expression for $\theta'$ precludes any fixed point for $r\not=0$ where $\theta$ is definable.

Comment: Thank you for your help!